# How to populate mongoose models with other key without using _id(objectId) in ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I am using MySQL data earlier. Now I am migrated to MongoDB. I want mongoose to populate some data. whereas I want to use `my own key` to populate in place of `_id(objectId)` in ref.

something like below.

Space schema

```
SpaceShema = mongoose.Schema({
 id: Number,
 cid: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: Client
  },
 space: String
});
```

> I want to use id in ClientShema to populate in place of ObjectId

Below is the client schema

```
ClientShema = mongoose.Schema({
 id: Number,
 client: String,
});
```

Comment: Do you want to add the client to the SpaceSchema at the `cid` . The id in `ClientScema` is a number so why don't you make the ` cid: {
  type: Number,
  ref: Client
  }` in `SpaceSchema`?

Comment: If we add `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` it will automatically searches the `_id`. If we add Number instead where it have to search if `ClientSchema` is having multiple `Number` **type key value pairs**. @jackblank